# Defining recrussive JSON Object notation

Tags: json

Whats wrong in below JSON Object definition

I am trying to create a new JSON Object like below.
So that my idea is to access COMPANYSETUP.HourSetup.initiate();

Not sure the error ?

```
COMPANYSETUP = {            
                    initiated : false,          
                     companyId : "",

            initiate : function() {
                if(!initiated){
                    // TO DO
                    initiated = true;
                }           },

            HourSetup = {
                initiated : false,
                    hourId : "",

                    initiate : function() {
                       if(!initiated){
                          // TO DO
                         initiated = true;
                        }
                   }

            }

        };
```

Comment: I think you confuse JSON with JavaScript objects. Your example is *not* JSON. I'd looks like you'd like to create some kind of module here.

Comment: Is this how your code is actually formatted regarding new lines? If so, the comments on lines 3 and 7 are commenting out the rest of the line, which will cause syntax errors.

Comment: I've tried to fix the codeblock and weird indentation. If this is how it's supposed to be, there's also a syntax error where HourSetup={} should be HourSetup: {}. Edit: OK, the weird indentation is back ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a javascript object and not JSON, which disallows functions,

HourSetup =

Should be changed to:

HourSetup :

<strike>Also, as JonoW points out, your single line comments are including some of your code as the code is formatted in the post.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

There's a "=" that shouldn't be there. Change it to ":"

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a form of JavaScript deliberately restricted for safety. It cannot include dangerous code elements like function expressions.

It should work OK in plain eval()ed JavaScript, but it's not JSON.